# Software to remove formatting on the clipboard automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, plain-text, text-processing, clipboard

I'm looking for a tool that will remove formatting on my clipboard **automatically** as I paste text. I would like the application to meet these requirements,

- Compatible with Windows 10
- Gratis

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Ability to turn on and off the automatic mode quickly (preferably with a keyboard shortcut)
- Ability to remove formatting by a keyboard shortcut even if the application is turned off the automatic mode
- Cross-platform (Available on Linux and OS X)

Note: Automatic mode meaning if on, it would automatically turn the formatted text into plain text without the user having to do anything.

Comment: You might be able to do this by holding the `Shift` key whilst using the built in keyboard shortcut for pasting.  In Windows and Linux this translates to Ctrl+Shift+V, no need for an external program.  Not sure if it works on a Mac

Comment: This is the sort of thing that's unlikely to be cross-platform but likely to be easy to do in a platform-specific framework (AutoHotKey, shell, Applescript or maybe shell).

Comment: @Gilles Agreed, but you never know whats out there

Comment: @gabe3886 And it doesn't work everywhere in Windows (e.g., doesn't work into MS Outlook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) mostly fits the bill. It does not replace the default paste functions but I quickly got used to using it's default of Win+V. Gave me the freedom to keep Ctrl+V should I want to retain the formatting. Using it like that negates the automatic mode requirement I suggest. It is however not cross platform.

[image]

Comment: I have been using PureText for years  on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, always  worked as expected.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't aware of this answer until now, works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use notepad.

You can paste any formatted text and it will only receive the plain, unformatted text.

Then you can Ctrl+A to select everything and Ctrl+C to copy the unformatted text.

[image]

It comes with Windows and you can thus consider it gratis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do this too but I was looking for something that essentially did this for me

Comment: I use the Windows Run box for the same purpose, which could potentially be faster: ctrl C, Win r, ctrl V, ctrl A, ctrl C - which takes about a second when you get used to doing this.